# Can I use Boost.Geometry.index.rtree with threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, r-tree, boost-geometry

I am trying to create a multithreaded spatial index using rtree from Boost.Geometry, however I am unable to determine if this is thread safe. I do not see any locking mechanisms inside rtree.hpp, but my C++/Boost knowledge is at a beginners level.

Is Boost.Geometry.index.rtree thread safe in any way? If not, what would be the optimal approach to use it with multiple threads in a safe manner (e.g. mutex lock between insert() calls? Am I able to query() at the same time as insert()?). Specifically I'm trying to get better query (read) performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is Boost.Geometry.index.rtree thread safe in any way?

No

> If not, what would be the optimal approach to use it with multiple threads in a safe manner (e.g. mutex lock between insert() calls?

Optimal? Depends.

You need mutual exclusion. You can do this with spinlocks, simple mutex, shared/upgradable mutex etc.

> Am I able to query() at the same time as insert()?).

Certainly not. That's called a data race and it's what you need the mutual exclusion (aka monitor) for in the first place.

> Specifically I'm trying to get better query (read) performance.

Adding threads doesn't make things faster. It makes things slower. Always.

The trick is that you can do *other things at the same time*.

---

You /can/ run multiple read-only operations in parallel. Usually, library containers are safe to use from multiple threads for read-only operations (although you might want to do a quick scan for any `mutable` members hidden( in the implementation).

Comment: Beautiful, thank you for the quick and concise answer, much appreciated!

Comment: Indeed, it should be safe to perform queries in multiple threads at the same time.

As for the creation, one could consider keeping one rtree per thread. At the beginning redistribute the input values across the threads (e.g. by first sorting them by X coordinate of a centroid) and for each chunk of data create a rtree. Then during the querying do the same, search for values in all rtrees at the same time. Then at the end gather the results from all of the threads.

Comment: @AdamWulkiewicz That is actually a neat idea, I'll give it a shot, thanks :)